# How should I extract a collection of distinct values from a List<T> of custom objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, lambda

I've got a List of objects - let's say they're Orders.

**Order**
`OrderID

Date

SalesmanId

...`

I want to extract a `Distinct` list of `SalesmanId`s from this list. What is the best way to do this? I don't suppose its looping through manually ...  is it?

**UPDATE**
Thanks for your responses. I've thought of an extra requirement (outlined after Jon Skeets answer) and coded it like this:

```
var salesusers = from s in lstOrders 
                 group s by new { s.SalesUserId,s.Username} 
                 into g  
                 select new { UserName = g.Key.Username, UserId = g.Key.SalesUserId };
```

It works, but I'm not sure if this is the right sort of approach or if I'm way off the mark?

Thanks.

**UPDATE #2:** 
This one ran and ran - newbies like me might find answers to this [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276974/working-with-lists-anonymous-types-and-suchlike/6277153#6277153) useful too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you only need to get the SalesmanIds, it's easy:

```
var salesmanIds = orders.Select(x => x.SalesmanId)
                        .Distinct();
```

Call `ToList()` if you need it as a `List<T>`.

You need a using directive for `System.Linq`.

EDIT: Okay, to get both the name and ID, you can use:

```
var salesmanIds = orders.Select(x => new { x.SalesmanId, x.UserName })
                        .Distinct();
```

Comment: @JonSkeet - Works like a charm (I knew it would...)

But ... to save myself another trip to the database I thought I'd join the Orders to the User table to get the usernames. But I'm not sure I can get both the SalesmanIds AND their usernames this way? Will I have to go back to old fashioned looping to do this?

Comment: @5arx: Do you actually have a list of orders, or is this in the database? What's the relationship between a salesman ID and a username?

Comment: @JonSkeet - the orders List is retrieved from the db by a query which joins the Salesman ID and Username from the Users table onto the Order.

I've been struggling away with this - please see my question edit above - would appreciate your opinion on whether this is the correct approach. I'm a veteran(ish) 40 year old dev and haven't got round to learning LINQ yet so this is all a bit of a voyage into the unknown :-(

Comment: @5arx: But is the username associated with the salesman? In other words, could you have multiple usernames for one salesman? If so, I suspect you should perform two separate queries.

Comment: @JonSkeet - yes - both username and userid could both effectively be used as PKs - the username is the first part of the email address. This being the case can I assume my solution is robust enough for production code?

Comment: @JonSkeet - crikey. That's quite a head-masher. I'm going to have to do some reading - it works perfectly, but at this point I have no real idea what's going on :-/

Comment: @5arx: How comfortable are you with the idea of anonymous types in general?

Comment: @JonSkeet - Not overly - in general I find all this dynamic C# stuff rather unsettling. I'm an older gent and like the security of compile-time checking and type-safety :-o

But in all fairness I haven't really done much LINQ or lambda programming. I'm old skool and am a Java coder by training so some things were drilled into me and are hard to un-think ...

Comment: @5arx: There's nothing dynamic here. You've still got compile-time checking and type-safety. If you tried to use a property of the anonymous type which wasn't specified at compile-time, you'd still get a compile-time error. Anonymous types are created by the *compiler*, not at execution time.

Comment: @JonSkeet - ah yes thanks. I see now, my mistake, I'm using the word 'dynamic' incorrectly - just noticed the class members do get  picked up by intellisense so it is type-safe. But still somewhat disorientating at present. More reading is definitely required - can you recommend an article or book on these newer language features. I already have yours so theres no need to plug it here   ;-)
(it is excellent btw)

Comment: @5arx: The language spec? That's where I normally go :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer this way:

Implement the  [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) interface for **Order** (just so you can properly compare them.

Then just do:

```
IEnumerable<Order> myDistinctOrders = oredersList.Distinct();
```