# Working with Lists, Anonymous Types and Suchlike

Tags: c#, list, sorting, anonymous-types

Following on from an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266022/how-should-i-extract-a-collection-of-distinct-values-from-a-listt-of-custom-obj), I now have a collection of an anonymous type

[User: 
    Username (as `forename.surname`,
    UserId
].

This collection of 'users' will ultimately need to be bound to a dropdown list. This is fine, but what I need to do is sort them by Surname and forename. but this is complicated by the fact that the username format is forename.surname.

At a high-level, this will involve a `Split` on the string to separate the name components, then `ToTitleCase()` both parts, then store the new values in another object within a List which I can then sort using `List<T>.OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)`

It occurred to me that all this fancy new syntax I'm attempting to learn might include a way of performing this process in a couple of lines of terse code. Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Thanks.

**EDIT 3:**

I think I've cracked it:

```
var salesusers =    (
                      from s in lstReport 
                      group s by new { s.SalesUserId,s.Username} 
                      into g
                      select new
                          {
                             Username = g.Key.Username.Split('.')[1].ToTitleCase() + " " + g.Key.Username.Split('.')[0].ToTitleCase(),
                             Surname = g.Key.Username.Split('.')[1].ToTitleCase(),
                             Forename = g.Key.Username.Split('.')[0].ToTitleCase(),
                             UserId = g.Key.SalesUserId 
                           }
                     ).OrderBy(a=> a.Surname).ThenBy(a=> a.Forename);
```

I need to create the separate forename and surname fields from the Username for sorting purposes and the Username for binding to a dropdownlist. It seems insane but it works so nicely I'm sticking with it for now. Would appreciate your comments.

**EDIT2:**
So I got as far as this. Now I'm wondering if the syntax will allow  me to combine the `Group by` operation from my earlier question with this step..

```
var sortedUsers = from u in salesusers
                  orderby u.UserName.Split('.')[1], u.UserName.Split('.')[0]
                  select new {UserName = u.UserName.Replace(".", " ").ToTitleCase(), UserId = u.UserId.Value};
```

Anybody ...?

**EDIT:** I managed to do <strike>it all</strike> most of it myself, in case anyone is ever needing, but converting the name components `ToTitleCase` during the ordering operation is proving difficult.

This:

```
var sortedUsers = from u in salesusers
                  orderby u.UserName.Split('.')[1], u.UserName.Split('.')[0]
                  select u;
```

seems to do <strike>the trick</strike> everything I need apart from the `ToTitleCase`ing. But of course there may be an even quicker/terser/more elegant method so I'll leave this open for a day or two to see what turns up ;-)

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do ToTitleCase in case of Linq to SQL.. as there is no corresponding SQL construct to do what ToTitleCase does hence linq2sql wont be able to parse the expression to SQL. But you can do ToTitleCase in the collection object after fetching data from SQL

Comment: @BillTheLizard - Done.

@Ankur - my solution (under 'EDIT 3' below OP) works ok. ToTitleCase() is a quick n dirty extension method I wrote that uses the method of the TextInfo object. I don't deal with LINQ to SQL here - the original collection is retrieved from the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the final solution I came up with - it sorts, `ToTitleCase`s and formats. Rather nifty if I say so myself. Took me all morning tho :-(

```
var salesusers =    (
                        from s in lstReport 
                        group s by new { s.SalesUserId,s.Username} 
                        into g
                        select new
                            {
                                Username = g.Key.Username.Split('.')[1].ToTitleCase() + " " + g.Key.Username.Split('.')[0].ToTitleCase(),  
                                Surname = g.Key.Username.Split('.')[1].ToTitleCase(),  
                                Forename = g.Key.Username.Split('.')[0].ToTitleCase(),  
                                UserId = g.Key.SalesUserId 
                             }  
                     ).OrderBy(a=> a.Surname).ThenBy(a=> a.Forename);
```

Answer (score 1):

A little less code can be achieved using lambdas rather than expression syntax as so

```
var sorted = salesusers.OrderBy(u => u.UserName.Split('.')[1]).ThenBy(u => u.UserName.Split('.')[0]).ToList();
```

although it is less readable but once you are used to the syntax I find it easier than the expression syntax to read.

EDIT: changes for edit 3

Your code converted to Lambdas is as follows

```
var salesusers = (l.GroupBy(s => new { SalesUserId = s.SalesUserId, Username = s.Username }).Select(g =>new {
                                Username = g.Key.Username.Split('.')[1].ToTitleCase() + " " + g.Key.Username.Split('.')[0].ToTitleCase(),
                                Surname = g.Key.Username.Split('.')[1].ToTitleCase(),
                                Forename = g.Key.Username.Split('.')[0].ToTitleCase(),
                                UserId = g.Key.SalesUserId
                    })).OrderBy(a => a.Surname).ThenBy(a => a.Forename);
```

The only thing is that the bigger the expression gets the harder it gets to read!

Another way you could do it which reads cleaner is to define the details object rather than using a dynamic object.

```
internal class UserDetails
    {
        public UserDetails(User u)
        {
            this.Forename = u.Username.Split('.')[0].ToTitleCase();
            this.Surname = u.Username.Split('.')[1].ToTitleCase();
            this.UserId = u.SalesUserId;
            this.Username = u.Username;
        }

        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Forename { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }

    }
```

then you can do

```
var salesusers = (l.GroupBy(s => new { SalesUserId = s.SalesUserId, Username = s.Username })
    .OrderBy(u => u.Username.Split('.')[1].ToTitleCase())
    .ThenBy(u => u.Username.Split('.')[0].ToTitleCase())
    .Select(g => new UserDetails(g)));
```

but this is more code which I'm not sure you want.

LATEST EDITS:

your Code doesn't require the group by statement so you could reduce that by doing

```
 var salesusers = (
                    from s in l
                        select new
                        {
                            Username = s.Username.Split('.')[1].ToTitleCase() + " " + s.Username.Split('.')[0].ToTitleCase(),
                            Surname = s.Username.Split('.')[1].ToTitleCase(),
                            Forename = s.Username.Split('.')[0].ToTitleCase(),
                            UserId = s.SalesUserId
                        }
                 ).OrderBy(a => a.Surname).ThenBy(a => a.Forename);
```

Or using Lambdas becomes

```
var salesusers = l.Select(g =>new {
                            Username = g.Username.Split('.')[1].ToTitleCase() + " " + g.Username.Split('.')[0].ToTitleCase(),
                            Surname = g.Username.Split('.')[1].ToTitleCase(),
                            Forename = g.Username.Split('.')[0].ToTitleCase(),
                            UserId = g.SalesUserId
                }).OrderBy(a => a.Surname).ThenBy(a => a.Forename);
```

Other than that the only way I can see to reduce that call further is with a defined class as above, thats not to say it can't be done! but I can't see how!

HTH

OneShot

Comment: +1 - Considerably less readable to my old eyes, but nice n' terse. Am I correct in assuming this is functionally identical to my solution?

Comment: @OneSHOT - please see my edit to the question - not sure its possible to do what I want ...

Comment: @OneSHOT - great minds think [almost] alike - see my 'final solution' below - I think it does the same thing but with a more f4cked-about-with anonymous class. Would appreciate your comments.

Comment: @OneSHOT - Many thanks - that's an intimidating bit of code! At my current level of understanding I think my attempt is more readable/maintainable though.

Comment: @5arx see "LATEST EDITS:" above. and I agree when the expression gets large if you aren't used to Lambda syntax it can be daunting but I still think that once a dev is used to the syntax it becomes as easy or easier to read than the full Linq expression syntax

Comment: @OneSHOT - I'm using the Group By in the first instance to do the equivalent of a DISTINCT (see the *earlier question* for details). I'm willing to bet my shirt on you having a more elegant solution to this too - are you a gamblin' man ...?

Comment: @5arx ah I hadn't noticed the earlier question, In which case the smallest amount of code I can think of at the minute that covers it is the snippet above that directly follows "EDIT: changes for edit 3", although if I have time later I'll see if I can come up with anything else!